# Livecycle hide/show sections based on user input

Tags: javascript, forms, adobe, livecycle-designer

I am trying to create a livecycle form where you can hide/show sections based on user input.

I am using Radio buttons to indicate which section should be visible based on the selected radio button. There will be many throughout the form and I require the form to flow and have no white spaces. Can you show me how to create the conditions?

I have many sections and I know the content of the section needs to be set to flowed but do I do this on the main form or on each section? Depending on which subform I chose to make the content flowed it can change the layout of the sections objects which I dont want so I may need advise on how to correct this as well. 
I dont have any experience with Livecycle other than creating simple forms. I have tried to find help on this all over the web but nothing shows me quite what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to use this code on my one of my radio buttons. It is set out exactly as below on the change event:

```
if (this.rawValue == "1")
{    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.1").presence="visible";      
    xfa.resolveNode("Section3").presence= "hidden";    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.2").presence = "hidden"    
}
else (this.rawValue == "0")
{    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.1").presence = "hidden";    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section3").presence= "hidden";    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.2").presence = "hidden";

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to convert an adobe livecycle form to an html form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to make the root subform (Page) layout flowable not positioned.
This will automatically reposition the containing subforms upon the show/hide behavior.

your code should say:

```
if (this.rawValue == 1)
{    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.1").presence="visible";      
    xfa.resolveNode("Section3").presence= "hidden";    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.2").presence = "hidden"    

else if (this.rawValue == 2)
{    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.1").presence = "hidden";    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section3").presence= "hidden";    
    xfa.resolveNode("Section2.Section2.2").presence = "hidden";

}
```

I tend to use the click event instead of the change event with radio buttons such as this.

cheers

Comment: thanks for this btw - I was struggling with my own version and realized i had uppercase IF.